# Table rotation with sidewaystable

Tags: tables, rotating

I rotated a table using sidewaystable but the first and last 4 cells of the first row appear with a wrong vertical alignment. Can anyone solve this problem?
[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside,b5paper,12pt,fleqn]{psd_thesis}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}           \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxmath,newtxtext}                
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabulary}                                                           
% Include the following packages 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}  % for \toprule, \midrule, and \bottomrule macros 

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

%\begin{footnotesize}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\scriptsize
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ C{1.1cm} C{1.1cm} C{1.1cm} C{1.1cm} C{1.1cm} C{1.1cm}      C{1.1cm} C{1.1cm} C{1.1cm} C{1.1cm} C{1.1cm} C{1.1cm} C{1.1cm} }    
%\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c c c c c c c}
\toprule
Sv,ieq  &   000436xa    &   000594xa    &   001715xa    &   001932ya    &     006040ya  &   006263xa    &   007162ya    &   007257ya    &   IT0605ya    &     IT0790xa  &   emiliaeo-retro  &   emilians-retro  \\   \midrule
0.4 &   2.447   &   2.177   &   2.304   &   4.921   &   4.298   &   2.121   &   3.928   &   3.478   &   3.462   &   1.751   &   0.875   &   0.525   \\    \hline
0.8 &   4.894   &   4.354   &   4.609   &   9.843   &   8.597   &   4.241   &   7.857   &   6.957   &   6.924   &   3.502   &   1.750   &   1.049   \\   \hline
1.2 &   7.341   &   6.530   &   6.913   &   14.764  &   12.895  &   6.362   &   11.785  &   10.435  &   10.386  &   5.252   &   2.625   &   1.574   \\   \hline
1.6 &   9.789   &   8.707   &   9.218   &   19.686  &   17.194  &   8.482   &   15.713  &   13.914  &   13.848  &   7.003   &   3.500   &   2.099   \\   \hline
2   &   12.236  &   10.884  &   11.522  &   24.607  &   21.492  &   10.603  &   19.642  &   17.392  &   17.310  &   8.754   &   4.375   &   2.624   \\   \hline
2.4 &   14.683  &   13.061  &   13.827  &   29.529  &   25.791  &   12.723  &   23.570  &   20.871  &   20.772  &   10.505  &   5.250   &   3.148   \\   \hline
2.8 &   17.130  &   15.237  &   16.131  &   34.450  &   30.089  &   14.844  &   27.498  &   24.349  &   24.234  &   12.256  &   6.125   &   3.673   \\   \hline
3.2 &   19.577  &   17.414  &   18.435  &   39.372  &   34.388  &   16.965  &   31.427  &   27.828  &   27.697  &   14.006  &   7.000   &   4.198   \\   \hline
3.6 &   22.024  &   19.591  &   20.740  &   44.293  &   38.686  &   19.085  &   35.355  &   31.306  &   31.159  &   15.757  &   7.875   &   4.723   \\   \hline
4   &   24.471  &   21.768  &   23.044  &   49.215  &   42.984  &   21.206  &   39.283  &   34.784  &   34.621  &   17.508  &   8.750   &   5.247   \\   \hline
4.4 &   26.919  &   23.945  &   25.349  &   54.136  &   47.283  &   23.326  &   43.212  &   38.263  &   38.083  &   19.259  &   9.625   &   5.772   \\   \hline
4.8 &   29.366  &   26.121  &   27.653  &   59.058  &   51.581  &   25.447  &   47.140  &   41.741  &   41.545  &   21.009  &   10.500  &   6.297   \\   \hline
5.2 &   31.813  &   28.298  &   29.957  &   63.979  &   55.880  &   27.567  &   51.068  &   45.220  &   45.007  &   22.760  &   11.375  &   6.821   \\   \hline
5.6 &   34.260  &   30.475  &   32.262  &   68.900  &   60.178  &   29.688  &   54.996  &   48.698  &   48.469  &   24.511  &   12.250  &   7.346   \\   \hline
6   &   36.707  &   32.652  &   34.566  &   73.822  &   64.477  &   31.809  &   58.925  &   52.177  &   51.931  &   26.262  &   13.125  &   7.871   \\       \bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption}
\end{sidewaystable}
%\end{footnotesize}

\end{document}
```

The psd_thesis.cls is reported below:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{psd_thesis}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}

\ProcessOptions

\LoadClass{report}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}  % Double-spaced

\usepackage[round]{natbib}  % bib style

%\usepackage[tx]{sfmath}      % a package of fonts
%\usepackage{helvet}             % For Helvetica (Arial is just a bad copy of Helvetica)
%\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}  

\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
\vspace*{50\p@}%  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \large \scshape \bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
    \par\nobreak
    \vskip 20\p@
\fi
\interlinepenalty\@M
\large \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
\vskip 40\p@  }}

\renewcommand{\@makeschapterhead}[1]{%
\vspace*{50\p@}%{\parindent \z@ \raggedright
\normalfont
\interlinepenalty\@M
\large \scshape \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
\vskip 40\p@  }}  

\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}% % the name{1}% % the level{0mm}% % the indent{3.0\baselineskip}% % the before skip{2.5\baselineskip}% % the after skip{\normalfont \normalsize}} % the style

\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection{subsection}% % the name
{2}% % the level{0mm}% % the indent{-\baselineskip}% % the before skip{1.5\baselineskip}% % the after skip{\normalfont \normalsize}} % the style

\endinput
```

Comment: Is the `psd_thesis` document class available online? Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made test with document class `book`, since your problem is tied with definition of `\newcolumtype`. Instead yours try to use:

```
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
```

and align of texts in the first row will become:

[image]

In test I use for page layout package `geometry` with option `b5paper` and `showframe`. The latter option is only for seeing page layout. With this option your table is to wide, so I alo add `\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}`. So my preamble and few rows of table was:

```
    \documentclass[twoside,12pt,fleqn]{book}
        \usepackage[b5paper,showframe]{geometry}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    %\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
    %\usepackage{newtxmath,newtxtext}
    %\usepackage{textgreek}
    \usepackage{rotating}
    %\usepackage{pdflscape}
    %\usepackage{tabulary}
    % Include the following packages
    %\usepackage{amsmath} % second time ...
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{booktabs}  % for \toprule, \midrule, and \bottomrule macros
    \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

    \begin{document}
        \begin{sidewaystable}
    \scriptsize
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
        \begin{tabular}{ C{1.1cm} C{1.1cm} C{1.1cm} C{1.1cm} C{1.1cm} C{1.1cm}      C{1.1cm} C{1.1cm} C{1.1cm} C{1.1cm} C{1.1cm} C{1.1cm} C{1.1cm} }
    %\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c c c c c c c}
    \toprule
    Sv,ieq  &   000436xa    &   000594xa    &   001715xa    &   001932ya    &     006040ya  &   006263xa    &   007162ya    &   007257ya    &   IT0605ya    &     IT0790xa  &   emiliaeo-retro  &   emilians-retro  \\   \midrule

    \end{tabular}
\caption{Caption}
    \end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:** 
First off-topic. To my taste the table will look better if you

- use `S` column type from `siunitx` package
- omit all `\hline` in table

In this case code becomes:

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt,fleqn]{book}
    \usepackage[b5paper,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}  % for \toprule, \midrule, and \bottomrule macros
\usepackage{siunitx}  % for better formatting columns with decimal numbers

\begin{document}
    \begin{sidewaystable}
\scriptsize
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}S[table-format=1.1]*{12}{S[table-format=2.3]}@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{11}{c}{}   &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{retro}   \\
    \cmidrule{12-13}
{Sv,ieq} & {000436xa} & {000594xa} & {001715xa} & {001932ya}    & {006040ya}  & {006263xa}    & {007162ya} & {007257ya} & {IT0605ya} & {IT0790xa}  & {emiliaeo} &  {emilians} \\   \midrule
0.4 &   2.447   &   2.177   &   2.304   &   4.921   &   4.298   &   2.121   &   3.928   &   3.478   &   3.462   &   1.751   &   0.875   &   0.525   \\    
0.8 &   4.894   &   4.354   &   4.609   &   9.843   &   8.597   &   4.241   &   7.857   &   6.957   &   6.924   &   3.502   &   1.750   &   1.049   \\   
1.2 &   7.341   &   6.530   &   6.913   &   14.764  &   12.895  &   6.362   &   11.785  &   10.435  &   10.386  &   5.252   &   2.625   &   1.574   \\  
...
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Caption}
    \end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

and gives:

[image]

Regarding additional question in your comment:

1. Table in my test is centeret on page
2. don't do it this. Table already ocupay whole text height and any further reducing font in table will make it not readable. Also is natural that caption is below or above table

Comment: @Zarco I solved that problem using \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}} and \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}

There is another problem now: my table is aligned at the top of the page, how can I move it to the center?

Moreover I would like the caption with the normal orientation, not rotated, can you solve this problem as well?

Thank you in advance

Comment: See addendum to my answer.

Comment: +1 for trying to dissuade the OP from placing the caption in a different place.

Comment: @Zarco I want to have on top the first row with a column of 1 cell and a multicolumn of 12 cells and the second a row of 13 columns. If possible I would like the vertical alignment of the first single column in the middle of the first 2 rows. The rest of the rows from 3 onward below should be of 13 columns. 
Do you have suggestions? Thank you

Comment: I would like to have on the top a row with a single column on the left and then a multicolumn of 12 cells. Then the second row should be of 13 columns. The content of the first single column should have the vertical alignment in the middle of the first and second rows. Can anyone solve this problem mantaining the columns large C{1.1cm}? Thank you. I tried this: 
'\begin{tabular}{c{1.1} c{1.1} c{1.1} c{1.1} c{1.1} c{1.1} c{1.1} c{1.1} c{1.1} c{1.1} c{1.1} c{1.1} }
\toprule
{single column}   &   \multicolumn{12}{c}{multicolumn}   \\
    \cmidrule{2-13}'

Comment: It seems that my comment, where I respond on your previous comment somehow disappear ... I don't understand you, what you like to obtain. The first version of answer gives exactly what was your request. From your comments I can only conclude that you don't like the nicer second solution in addendum of my answer :-(. I suggest you to ask new question, since your question in comment is not very visible to other member of SE and not clear to me (so I cant help you). In it please clarify, what you like to obtain and what is your problem in this.

Answer (score 3):

(I can't get your custom document class to work -- too many error messages. In what follows, I use the `report` document class, largely because the `psd_thesis` class appears to be built on the `report` class.)

First and foremost, you need to make sure that the table fits inside the text block. (As one can tell from the screenshot you've posted, your table is currently much too wide.) I suggest you use a `tabularx` environment (with width set to `\textwidth`) instead of a `tabular` environment with fixed-width columns. Getting rid of the AFAICT unnecessary `\hspace{0pt}` directive inside the definition of the `C` column type let you get rid of the vertical spacing anomaly you've encountered.

I would further like to recommend that you align the numbers on their respective decimal markers; this will make it easier on your readers to actually take in the information you're looking to provide. Do also consider getting rid of all `\hline` directives and simply adding a bit more vertical whitespace after every fifth data row.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside,b5paper,12pt,fleqn]{report}
\usepackage{geometry,amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}           
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxmath,newtxtext}                
\usepackage{rotating,tabularx,booktabs,siunitx,caption}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\scriptsize
\captionsetup{size=scriptsize} % match font size to body of table
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}  % less space between columns
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} 
          S[table-format=1.1] *{11}{S[table-format=2.3]} S[table-format=1.3] @{}}
\toprule
{Sv,ieq} & \mc{000436xa} & \mc{000594xa} & \mc{001715xa} & \mc{001932ya} & 
\mc{006040ya} & \mc{006263xa} & \mc{007162ya} & \mc{007257ya} & 
\mc{IT0605ya} & \mc{IT0790xa} & \mc{emiliaeo-retro} & \mc{emilians-retro}  \\   
\midrule
0.4 &   2.447   &   2.177   &   2.304   &   4.921   &   4.298   &   2.121   &   3.928   &   3.478   &   3.462   &   1.751   &   0.875   &   0.525   \\    
0.8 &   4.894   &   4.354   &   4.609   &   9.843   &   8.597   &   4.241   &   7.857   &   6.957   &   6.924   &   3.502   &   1.750   &   1.049   \\   
1.2 &   7.341   &   6.530   &   6.913   &   14.764  &   12.895  &   6.362   &   11.785  &   10.435  &   10.386  &   5.252   &   2.625   &   1.574   \\   
1.6 &   9.789   &   8.707   &   9.218   &   19.686  &   17.194  &   8.482   &   15.713  &   13.914  &   13.848  &   7.003   &   3.500   &   2.099   \\   
2   &   12.236  &   10.884  &   11.522  &   24.607  &   21.492  &   10.603  &   19.642  &   17.392  &   17.310  &   8.754   &   4.375   &   2.624   \\   
\addlinespace  % a bit more space after every 5th row
2.4 &   14.683  &   13.061  &   13.827  &   29.529  &   25.791  &   12.723  &   23.570  &   20.871  &   20.772  &   10.505  &   5.250   &   3.148   \\   
2.8 &   17.130  &   15.237  &   16.131  &   34.450  &   30.089  &   14.844  &   27.498  &   24.349  &   24.234  &   12.256  &   6.125   &   3.673   \\   
3.2 &   19.577  &   17.414  &   18.435  &   39.372  &   34.388  &   16.965  &   31.427  &   27.828  &   27.697  &   14.006  &   7.000   &   4.198   \\   
3.6 &   22.024  &   19.591  &   20.740  &   44.293  &   38.686  &   19.085  &   35.355  &   31.306  &   31.159  &   15.757  &   7.875   &   4.723   \\   
4   &   24.471  &   21.768  &   23.044  &   49.215  &   42.984  &   21.206  &   39.283  &   34.784  &   34.621  &   17.508  &   8.750   &   5.247   \\   
\addlinespace
4.4 &   26.919  &   23.945  &   25.349  &   54.136  &   47.283  &   23.326  &   43.212  &   38.263  &   38.083  &   19.259  &   9.625   &   5.772   \\   
4.8 &   29.366  &   26.121  &   27.653  &   59.058  &   51.581  &   25.447  &   47.140  &   41.741  &   41.545  &   21.009  &   10.500  &   6.297   \\   
5.2 &   31.813  &   28.298  &   29.957  &   63.979  &   55.880  &   27.567  &   51.068  &   45.220  &   45.007  &   22.760  &   11.375  &   6.821   \\   
5.6 &   34.260  &   30.475  &   32.262  &   68.900  &   60.178  &   29.688  &   54.996  &   48.698  &   48.469  &   24.511  &   12.250  &   7.346   \\   
6   &   36.707  &   32.652  &   34.566  &   73.822  &   64.477  &   31.809  &   58.925  &   52.177  &   51.931  &   26.262  &   13.125  &   7.871   \\       
\bottomrule 
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Caption}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) ... you bit me for time which I need to typing answers in Op comment (this evening I'm extra slow ... :-(